# Jquery append oly getting last elemen in loop Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Hi Guys I am noob at jquery and i have this problems i am trying to display an image preview when the user load the file I found some post but cant get it to work It only displays the last image

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var counter = 0
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var img = '';
        reader.onload = function (e) {

          debugger
          img.attr('src', e.target.result)
          .width(150)
          .height(150);

          $('.test').append(img.clone());
          console.log(img);
        }

        for(var i=0; i< input.files.length; i++){
          img = $('<img id="dynamic'+i+'" style="margin-top : 5px;  margin-right: 5px;">');
          reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
          counter++;
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the a piece of the haml form

```
  .form-group
    = f.label :proyecto_imagenes, "Imágenes de proyecto", class: 'col-xs-2'
    .col-xs-8
      = f.file_field :imagenes, multiple: true
      %br
      .test
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
      (function(i) {
        var img = $('<img id="dynamic' + i + '" style="margin-top : 5px;  margin-right: 5px;">');
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
          img.prop('src', e.target.result).width(150).height(150).appendTo('.test');
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
      })(i)
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" onchange="readURL(this)" multiple/>
<div class='test'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot men It works like it suppose to  awesome

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to bind your function to an event. Something like:

Please notice the changes:

```
   .form-group
     = f.label :proyecto_imagenes, "Imágenes de proyecto", class: 'col-xs-2 file-input'
       .col-xs-8
         = f.file_field :imagenes, multiple: true
         %br
         #test
```

And this is the trigger

```
$(function(){
     $(".file-input").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
     });
})
```

And your function:

```
var readURL = function(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
          $('#test').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

LE: I don't recommend you too add the styling from javascript, unless you have no other choice.